# How to access index of a class label in from mxnet nd array? The output must be index of the label name entered with function

Tags: python, arrays, function, indexing, mxnet

```
#pred_probas is probabilities of each class type
def find_class_idx(label):
    """
    Should return the class index of a particular label.

    :param label: label of class
    :type label: str

    :return: class index
    :rtype: int
    """
    #ind = mx.nd.argmax(label, axis=1).astype('int')
    topk_indices=mx.nd.topk(pred_probas,k=100)
    return max(topk_indices)*100
```

Answer (score 0):

As the network output classes of GluonCV are of list type. We can access index of list using this function list.index(label)

```
def find_class_idx(label):
"""
Should return the class index of a particular label.

:param label: label of class
:type label: str

:return: class index
:rtype: int
"""

return network.classes.index(label)
```